# LEAD function with no next transaction for certain records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple customers. Some of them only made one transaction, whereas other made more of them. I would like to run a query that would help me see, for each customer, the first two transactions, their timestamp and the amount of money spent. For this I am using the following query:

```
select t.* 
from 
  (select customer_id, 
    transaction_type as tx_0, 
    transaction_timestamp as tx_0_time, amount as tx_0_amount,
    lead(transaction_type, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_timestamp) as tx_1,
    lead(transaction_timestamp, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_timestamp) as tx_1_time
    lead(amount, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_timestamp) as tx_1_amount,
  from payment_table 
  ) t
right join 
  (select customer_id, min(transaction_timestamp) as minimal
  from payment_table
  where transaction_type = 'Buy'
  group by customer_id) s
on t.customer_id = s.customer_id and t.tx_0_time = s.minimal
where tx_0 = 'Buy'
and tx_1 in ('Buy', '', null)
```

I only want to get specific types of transactions (== 'Buy'), and I would like to get only the first two transactions ever.

The query works properly, but only for those customers who made at least two transactions. If a customer made just one transaction, he does not appear in the results. Is there a way to fix the query so that for customers who did not make the second transaction, I will get blanks for columns related to the second transaction?

Comment: please provide sample data and structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All NULLs in `t.tx_1` will be filtered out by your second `WHERE` condition.

Remember that NULL behaves differently from other values, and `NULL IN ('Buy', '', null)` will result in NULL rather than TRUE.

You should rewrite that condition as

```
(t.tx_1 IS NULL OR t.tx_1 = 'Buy')
```

or, more concise, but also more cryptical,

```
coalesce(t.tx_1, 'Buy') = 'Buy'
```

Alternatively, move the comparison to the join condition!

Comment: This worked perfectly. It was a problem with the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` in the `IN` does not match anything, so that is a problem.  However, you are doing a `JOIN` where none is necessary:

```
select distinct on (customer_id) t.* 
from (select customer_id, 
             transaction_type as tx_0, 
             transaction_timestamp as tx_0_time,
             amount as tx_0_amount,
             lead(transaction_type, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_timestamp) as tx_1,
             lead(transaction_timestamp, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_timestamp) as tx_1_time
             lead(amount, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_timestamp) as tx_1_amount
      from payment_table 
     ) t
where tx_0 = 'Buy' and (tx_1 = 'Buy' or tx_1 is null)
order by customer_id, tx_0_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the join, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to filter to the first row for each customer. Also, you don't need to include `transaction_type` for either transaction in the end result, you can just filter on it, since you're only interested in `Buy` transactions.

```
SELECT customer_id, tx_0_time, tx_0_amount, tx_1_time, tx_1_amount
FROM 
  (SELECT
     customer_id,
     transaction_timestamp AS tx_0_time,
     amount AS tx_0_amount,
     lead(transaction_timestamp, 1)
       OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_timestamp)
       AS tx_1_time,
     lead(amount, 1)
       OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_timestamp)
       AS tx_1_amount,
     row_number()
       OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_timestamp)
       AS rn
   FROM payment_table
   WHERE transaction_type = 'Buy'
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```